SSL Error connecting to Azure SQL

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
error occurred during the pre-login handshake

I am getting this error when testing from SSMS and also from linked servers and SSIS providers.
Around the 4th November, this connection stopped working.  I see that TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were due to be deprecated on 31st October 2024 so I suspect this is related to this event.
However, I am getting this on a newly installed Dev server which is Windows Server 2022 and I am also seeing this on the Production server which is Windows Server 2012.
I have disabled the TLS 1.0 and 1.1 using IIS Crypto and also disabled in the registry using these keys
SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client
SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server
SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server
